# unique random number generator in google forms

Tags: random, google-forms

I've set up a survey using google forms. Now I want to show a unique-random number in the confirmation page for each participants.
Is anyone aware of a quick reliable way?
Thanks

Answer (score -3):

how about asking each participant to create a unique code using their initials and date of birth? I believe that would serve the same function if you are trying to assign a unique identifier to each participant.

Comment: And what if you want to know "which user" created this code? What if multiple people said they have created that code? Can you know who is right in this case?